# The ajax function I created does not delete cookies

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, session-cookies, httpcookie

I am trying to delete cookies once an "a" is pressed. So I thought of using ajax like this:

```
<?php 
$logged = false;
if (isset($_COOKIE["psw"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usn"])){
    $logged = true;

    ?> 
    <script>
    console.log("status: Logged");
    var ahr = document.getElementById('ahr');
    ahr.setAttribute('href', '');
    ahr.innerHTML="Log-out";

    ahr.onclick = function remokecookies() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'bottlesbeach.eu/ajax.php',
           data:{action:'removecks'},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
    }
    </script>
    
    <?
```

Then on the ajax.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'removecks') {
setcookie("usn", "", time() - 86400 * 30);
setcookie("psw", "", time() - 86400 * 30);
}
?>
```

But when I click on the "a" (which is "Logout", see bottlesbeach.eu) the page reloads but the cookies are not deleted (I check the cookies by clicking on cookies> bootlesbeach.eu> cookies).

My question is: **why are the "usn" and "psw" cookies not deleted?**

[cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiJgo.png)

My libs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!--sweet alert lib-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Basically, you don't make the request. You haven't included `jquery`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the libraries I include

Comment: I've checked and jQuery isn't on the page...

Comment: You also need to change the URL to a relative URL `url: '/ajax.php'`

Comment: Now the alert appears but the cookies are not deleted anyway

Comment: is not this? <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: That is working?

Comment: Yes, now working

Comment: The cookies are deleted correctly. Batsava add the library as you said and insert the relative address instead of the url

Comment: Your log on doesn't work though? and you definitely shouldn't have the username and password stored in the cookies!

Comment: I have yet to develop the access, and I believe that I will encrypt the content of the cookie

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt it you should have a separate table. Or just use `$_SESSION` (as you are using that anyway!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The reason that this doesn't work is that you haven't actually included the `jquery` library in you page.

You can fix this by adding the line...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

...to the head of your page.

Additionally you need to change the `url` in your ajax request to a relative `url`:

```
`url: '/ajax.php'
```

---

### Additional Notes

**Page Refresh**

While the above does *work* to remove the cookies. It doesn't update the page, for example, it still says "log out" in the menu until you refresh the page.

To combat this you should either make the page refresh when the ajax returns...

```
window.location.href = "/";
```

...or just set the link to a logout url...

```
<a href="/logout.php">Log out</a>
```

...and have that re-direct to the home page...

```
header("location: /");
```

**Cookie content**

You should *never* store sensitive information like passwords in a cookie, even if you encrypt it first.

Instead you should have a second table that links the user to a long, randomly generated, "session id". The session id is then sent back and forth in the cookie and the user id looked up in the database.

**Passwords**

I'm not sure how you store passwords on your server, however, they should ALWAYS be stored as a has and not in plain text. You can do this with inbuilt PHP functions...

```
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

...and verify the same way...

```
$loggedon = password_verify($_POST["password"], $db_password);
```

**Effects**

You should be careful when using effects to make the website dynamic. Personally I find it really annoying that the "logon" form expands and shrinks when it comes into and out of focus etc.

Comment: I am noticing that from mobile all this does not work (it does not remove cookies), while from desktop it works correctly.

Comment: Then, I wanted to ask: but is the user id generated randomly and placed on another mysql table? is this what you meant? but then how do i map the user id to the real credentials which are on another table

Comment: I'm not sure about on mobile, but now it appears that the whole logon system isn't working? (i.e. even when I'm logged on with cookies the front end doesn't show me as logged on)

Comment: I changed the authentication mode (I placed a cookie that contains some sort of token) everything works except on apple mobile devices. Check out my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754222/ajax-request-not-working-on-apple-devices?noredirect=1#comment118011144_66754222